# Introduce delay between image change in a loop

Tags: android

I am trying to introduce a delay between image change in a for loop. I tried Thread.sleep(1000), but the delay is introduced before the image change and after the total sleep period is over, the ImageView dispalys the final image. I tried a lot of solutions available on the internet but nothing works.

```
public void start(View view){
    ImageView display = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    for (int i=0;i<6;i++){
        display.setImageResource(R.drawable.dice1+i);
        Thread.sleep(2000);
    }
}
```

I need the iteration to wait for 2 seconds so that the image can be viewed.

Comment: 1. create `int[]` for your Resource and and iterate over array. 2. try using `AsyncTask` to perform your delay task and set image at `onPost()`

Comment: @Mohit AsyncTask isn't a a good idea.  For one thing, he doesn't want to do this on another thread, its a pure UI task.  For a second, there's no garuntee on the scheduling of async tasks.  Third, there's a single asynctask thread by default, which handles tasks round robin.  Sleeping on an async task will hold up all other tasks, and any other tasks would hold up this one.  AsyncTasks are not to be used as timers for this reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two problems.

1)Don't sleep on the main thread.  Ever.  Instead, create a Handler and use postDelayed with a Runnable that changes the image.

2)You can't do math on resource ids like that.  You can't assume they'll be consecutive just because they're next to each other in the file.  Create an array with the ids and use the image at index i.

Comment: I have named the images in alphabetical order so that they come in order...

Comment: No, they don't.  There is no promise that will happen.  What you're depending on is luck or an implementation detail of a particular version of the android sdk, this is not a promised behavior.

Comment: So if there are hundreds of image results in a game what method should I use... I can't create a switch case for all 100 pictures?

Comment: Like I said- an array with the image ids. You can then index into the array to get the right one

Comment: You dont need array of ids, Just look at my answer.

Comment: Yes, but your solution is less clear, more complicated, and less efficient (resource lookup by string name is slow).  AN array is the right solution.

Comment: I am not saying to always load the resource by name. Just load it by name once using a loop or by run time. Once an image loaded, cache the resource id. So when you ask the same image for second time, you will be already having the resource id. So you don't need to look p for resource by string again. By this the developer don't need to type all his resource in array. Load once, then reuse it again. He can change the range of images whenever he wants. More readable. 2secs per image is not that much expensive task i think

Comment: We'll have to agree to disagree on readability-  I'd flunk your solution on a code review.

Comment: Sorry, It's just an idea to load sequence image, Not the best one :p

Answer (score 0):

You can get the sequence of image by the image name as you asked

```
    private int image = 0;

    private static final int MAX_IMAGES = 10;

    private Handler mHandler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            super.handleMessage(msg);
            if (msg.what == 55) {
                image++;
                if (image > MAX_IMAGES) {
                    image = 1;
                }
                imageView.setImageDrawable(getImageByName("dice" + image, TestActivity.this));
                mHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(55, 2000);
            }
        }
    };

    public static Drawable getImageByName(String name, Context context) {
        Resources resources = context.getResources();
        final int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier(name, "drawable",
                context.getPackageName());
        return ContextCompat.getDrawable(context, resourceId);
    }
```

Now start the image sequence by calling

```
mHandler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(55, 2000);
```

Your image will be changed per 2 secs

Answer (score 0):

I think a CountDown timer can help in this situation. A few days ago I asked a similar question at [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56324121/is-there-an-approach-which-can-delay-certain-seconds-between-every-function-call), and I got this answer. I think it may be a good reference for you.